# why is it showing run time error ?it is not giving any output?

Tags: c

/*this code is for rotating the array with n no of entries k no of times 
           and    outputting the array elements at indexz q no of times*/ my problem here is that it is showing runtime error why is it happening like that.this question is  actually from hacker rank and it is by the name of circular array rotation in implimentation section in algorithms.is there anything wrong in this code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

    int n,k,q;
    int a[n];
    scanf("%d%d%d",&n,&k,&q);
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    for(int j=0;j<k;j++)/*this is for rotating the array*/
    {
        int y=a[n-1];
        for(int x=n-2;x>=0;x--)
            a[x+1]=a[x];
        a[0]=y;
    }  
    for(int b=0;b<q;b++)
    {
        int z;
        scanf("%d",&z);
        printf("%d\n",a[z]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "is there anything wrong in this code" - yes.

Comment: `int a[n];` - Can you tell what would be the size of this array?

Comment: Please format your code for readability.

Answer (score 3):

Problem:

```
int n,k,q;
int a[n];
```

You are creating an array of size `n` before setting the value of `n`.

Use:

```
int n,k,q;

// Read a value into n first
if ( scanf("%d%d%d",&n,&k,&q) != 3 )
{
   // Deal with error
   return 1;
}

// Then define the array.
int a[n];
```

Comment: Is it even legal to use a variable as the size of an array?

Comment: @hymie, Yes. Variable length arrays are part of the standard since C99.

Comment: Thanks. I learned C many years before that, and haven't kept up with the changing standards.